# How to get paid as remote developer working from Venezuela?

Tags: software-industry, salary, telecommute, developer, venezuela

Here in Venezuela We have a severe currency exchange control set by the government since 2003. This means that buying and selling any foreign currency freely is not 100% legal and is controlled by the government by several agencies like CADIVI, SICAD I and SICAD II, this means that you must fill several forms and have a credit card and a formal job to get a yearly dollar internet coupon of a maximum of 300$, and nothing more. So if there were some alternatives or ways to get paid remotely in a foreign currency it would be great.

For example if I want to buy a product outside of the country or even create a simple PayPal account (Because you must spend 1$ for the activation), I would need to get a credit card that I don't have because I don't have a formal job, and the purchase wouldn't be able to be over 300$.

For more information:

- [What is CADIVI?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CADIVI)

Comment: Bitcoin? If you find a way to sell them locally, they can evade all controls.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about international money transfers.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of three ways to solve your problem (of course there may be a hundred more ways :-)

### 1.) Paypal

My personal PayPal Account is in EUR. Each time I buy something overseas in USD (or any other currency), PayPal will directly do a currency exchange USD --> EUR (they earn money by transfer rates in this process) which means my PayPal account will be debited in EUR. So I can't think of any problem when you buy something via PayPal.

With receiving money it's similiar. Your PayPal account has a primary currency, but you can receive payments in other currencies. In that case you will be asked if you want to exchange that payment into your primary currency, or if you want to create a new balance with that currency inside your account.

So IMHO as long as you directly change the incoming currency, you'll never have any USD in your bank balance if you are using PayPal. But you'll want to check out if it's really allowed that way (I'm not a finance lawyer).

### 2.) Freelancing platforms

I think the big freelancing platforms will take care of that problem for you. Atleast oDesk has a method which they call LFT (Local funds transfer) which means that the bank of oDesk will care for the currency exchange (again you'll loose some money, because they make profit with the exchanges rates just like PayPal does), but you'll directly receive money in your currency to your bank account and you'll never see any USD. If you plan to use a freelancing plattform to reach your customers anyway, you may have a look at that.

### 3.) Western Union

Another possibility (and pretty common as a payment method for offshore work in the US as far as I know) is Western Union. Your client will be able to directly pay in USD and Western Union will automatically exchange the money into your currency, before tranferring it to your bank account, so you'll not directly receive any USD this way, too.

---

### Further Reading:

- [oDesk LFT](https://support.odesk.com/entries/23128402-Getting-Paid-in-India) (the link is about India but it applies to other countries, too).
- [PayPal receiving foreign currencies](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/mc/mc_receive-outside)
- [Western Union website](https://www.westernunion.com/us/en/send-money/start.html) (just choose Venezuela as target, it will automatically use USD --> VIB as currency.